# Find [R, C] in a 5*5 matrix of spiral order

Tags: c, search, matrix, spiral

For an N*N spiral matrix filled similar to one given above, find element present at [R,C] position where R=row’s number, C=column’s number.

Bare in mind I am still a beginner, so please nothing too advance.

I'm getting confused with the spiralling matrix, this would work also but it's designed for a regular matrix and I would like to understand the best solution given it's a spiral. Thank you.

```
#include<stdio.h>

 /* Searches the element x in mat[][]. If the element is found, 
    then prints its position and returns true, otherwise prints 
    "not found" and returns false */
int search(int mat[4][4], int n, int x)
{
   int i = 0, j = n-1;  //set indexes for top right element
   while ( i < n && j >= 0 )
   {
      if ( mat[i][j] == x )
      {
         printf("\n Found at %d, %d", i, j);
         return 1;
      }
      if ( mat[i][j] > x )
        j--;
      else //  if mat[i][j] < x
        i++;
   }

   printf("\n Element not found");
   return 0;  // if ( i==n || j== -1 )
}
```

Comment: First of all, what is the definition of spiral matrix?
Second of all, how are you trying to solve the problem using this code and what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Hint: the function prototype should be `int getnum(int n, int r, int c)`. The function doesn't need a copy of the matrix. In fact, this is mostly just a math question. So put the keyboard aside, and pick up a pencil and paper.

Comment: "Find [R, C] in a **5*5** matrix" - `int mat[4][4]` - Do you notice something?

Answer (score 0):

We shall use recursion here. Understand the fact that if the element to be searched is not a boundary element of a `NxN` spiral matrix, then we can remove the boundaries and check for the element in the now formed `(N-2)x(N-2)` spiral matrix.
The following peice of code uses this logic. (Note that `R` and `C` use *1-based indexing*)

```
import java.util.*;
class SpiralElement{
    static int getElement(int N, int R, int C){
        if(R != 1 && C != 1 && R != N && C != N)return getElement(N-2, R-1, C-1);        
        else{
            if(R == 1)return N*N+1-C;
            else if(C == 1)return (N*N) - (N)-(N-1)-(N-2) - (N-R);
            else if(R == N)return (N*N) - (N) - (N-1) - (N-2) + (C-1);
            else return (N*N) - (N) - (R-2);
        }
    }
    static void main(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter N, R, C");
        int N = sc.nextInt();
        int R = sc.nextInt();
        int C = sc.nextInt();
        if(N%2 == 0){
            R = N-R+1; // mirroring the position as highest element(N*N) is now the bottom-right element and not top-left
            C = N-C+1;
        }
        System.out.println(getElement(N,R,C));
    }
}
```